# setting MSI for hdinsight VMs inside Vnet

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-hdinsight, windows-installer

How can i set MSI for HDInsight linux VMs provisioned using ARM template or powershell `New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster`. I need the cluster to communicate with Azure services that support AD authentication.